# Selenium Webdriver with Java: How to select a random birth month and a random country from drop-down select options menu

Tags: java, webdriver

Im populating my website with dummy users, and I've randomized everything, except for the birth month and country/city.

can you help me find an easy way to do that?
This is the code I am using now, but its got Germany hardcoded into it :(

```
Select user_country = new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("user_country_id")));
user_country.selectByVisibleText("Germany");
```

Here is the html for the country drop-down list:

```
<div class="custom-select">
    <select id="user_country_id" class="validate" name="user[country_id]" data-cities-path="/country/id-replace/cities">
        <option value="51baca9bf325db50be000012">Japan</option>
        <option value="51baca9bf325db50be000015">China</option>
        <option value="51baca9bf325db50be00001c">Australia</option>
        <option value="51baca9bf325db50be000023">Thailand</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Are the ids fixed or they are dynamically generated ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you select by a random Index?

```
user_country.selectByIndex(new Random().nextInt(user_country.getOptions().size()));
```

Comment: amazing, this is exactly what I wanted - a simple method

Answer (score 1):

You can place the labels within an array an then select a random element from it, by using the [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class. Then, when you gen a random name of a country, you can pass it to the `Select` object.

```
String[] countriesArray = {"Japan", "Germany", "Australia", "Thailand"};
String randomLabel = countriesArray[new Random().nextInt(countriesArray.length)];

Select user_country = new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("user_country_id")));
user_country.selectByVisibleText(randomLabel);
```

Comment: but there are 200+ countries, how do I dynamically obtain these, so I can put them into an array? I've just shortened the example, so we keep it to the point.. I dont want to write it manually.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have it set up is by having a separate method for the random such as:

```
public int RandomSelectInt(List<IWebElement> elements)
{
    int options = elements.Count;
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.Next(1, options);
}
```

You can then call this method in your code when you add the items to the list something like:

```
public void selectCountry()
{ 
    IWebElement countryOptions = driver.FindElement(By.id("user_country_id");
    List<IWebElement> countryList = countryOptions.FindElements(By.TagName("Option")).ToList(); 
    new SelectElement(countryOptions).SelectByIndex(MethodPath.RandomSelectInt(countryList));
}
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

> try this

```
         long x = 1191L;
         long y = 1349L;
         Random r = new Random();
         long named = x+((long)(r.nextDouble()*(y-x)));


               /*WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
                    new Select(elem).selectByIndex(""+named);*/

                    Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[6]/div/a/span")));
                    dropdown.selectByValue(""+named);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
```